# CSS nth-child() and :eq() doesn't work in my code

Tags: css, css-selectors

In my code I try to acces the `a` links to make each one a different color.I have used `nth-child` or `:eq` but doesn't work.

I have a div wrapper and inside 3 divs each one with a link. I want to select each link with a number inside the offers div wrapper.

Please someone tell me if I picked up the wrong selector or if my CSS is wrong.

```css
.offers-box a:nth-of-type(1) {
  color: #3F265F;
}
.offers-box a:nth-of-type(2) {
  color: #F04B5B;
}
```

```html
<div class="offers m-t-50 m-b-15">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4 ">
      <div class="offers-box">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3>OFFRE STANDARD</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--row-->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h5>Votre activite &amp; commerce est optimises</h5>
            <ul>
              <li>Inclus:</li>
              <li>- Vitrine commerciale</li>
              <li>- Systeme de commerce</li>
              <li>- Systeme de reservation</li>
              <li>- Annonces commerciale "SEO"</li>
              <li>- Passerelle multidifusion auto: xml, etc</li>
              <li>- Passerelle multidifusion immo: idx, xml, etc</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--row-->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 text-center offers-button">
            <a href="#" title="Click here">DECOUVRIR L'OFFRE</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--row-->
      </div>
      <!--offers-box-->
    </div>
    <!--col-md-4-->



    <div class="col-md-4 ">
      <div class="offers-box">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3>OFFRE CORPORATE</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--row-->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h5>Votre activite &amp; commerce est optimises</h5>
            <ul>
              <li>Inclus:</li>
              <li>- Vitrine commerciale</li>
              <li>- Systeme de commerce</li>
              <li>- Systeme de reservation</li>
              <li>- Annonces commerciale "SEO"</li>
              <li>- Passerelle multidifusion auto: xml, etc</li>
              <li>- Passerelle multidifusion immo: idx, xml, etc</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--row-->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 text-center offers-button">
            <a href="#" title="Click here">DECOUVRIR L'OFFRE</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--row-->
      </div>
      <!--offers-box-->
    </div>
    <!--col-md-4-->



    <div class="col-md-4 ">
      <div class="offers-box offers-last-box">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3>COMMUNICATIONS STANDARD TELEPHONIQUE</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--row-->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <p><span class="blue-color">Le portail unifie</span> de vos communications d'entreprises</p>
            <img src="/images/image.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--row-->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 text-center offers-button">
            <a href="#" title="Click here">DECOUVRIR L'OFFRE</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--row-->
      </div>
      <!--offers-box-->
    </div>
    <!--col-md-4-->

  </div>
  <!--row-->
</div>
<!--offers-->
```

Comment: Every link is the 1st of type of it's div...There is no `nth-of-DOM` selector. You will need javascript.

Comment: or you could use the HTML structure to achieve what you want. see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the divs with class `.offers-box` are NOT **siblings** so you can't use `nth-child` or `first-child` etc.

`.offers-box:nth-of-type()` doesn't work because using `:nth-of-type(1)` will select all the `.offers-box` because every element with that class is the only child of its parent . `.offers-box` is the only child of the `col-md-4`

the same with `.offers-box a:nth-of-type()` , each `a` is the only `a` inside the `.offers-box` div

the three `.col-md-4`  are `siblings` and the **ONLY** `children` of the same parent `.offers > .row` so you can use them.

in each `.col-md-4` there is a `.offers-box` so use the below code to achieve what you need.

let me know if it works

```css
.col-md-4:first-child .offers-box a {
  color: red;
}
.col-md-4:nth-child(2) .offers-box a {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="offers m-t-50 m-b-15">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4 ">
      <div class="offers-box">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3>OFFRE STANDARD</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--row-->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h5>Votre activite &amp; commerce est optimises</h5>
            <ul>
              <li>Inclus:</li>
              <li>- Vitrine commerciale</li>
              <li>- Systeme de commerce</li>
              <li>- Systeme de reservation</li>
              <li>- Annonces commerciale "SEO"</li>
              <li>- Passerelle multidifusion auto: xml, etc</li>
              <li>- Passerelle multidifusion immo: idx, xml, etc</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--row-->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 text-center offers-button">
            <a href="#" title="Click here">DECOUVRIR L'OFFRE</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--row-->
      </div>
      <!--offers-box-->
    </div>
    <!--col-md-4-->



    <div class="col-md-4 ">
      <div class="offers-box">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3>OFFRE CORPORATE</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--row-->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h5>Votre activite &amp; commerce est optimises</h5>
            <ul>
              <li>Inclus:</li>
              <li>- Vitrine commerciale</li>
              <li>- Systeme de commerce</li>
              <li>- Systeme de reservation</li>
              <li>- Annonces commerciale "SEO"</li>
              <li>- Passerelle multidifusion auto: xml, etc</li>
              <li>- Passerelle multidifusion immo: idx, xml, etc</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--row-->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 text-center offers-button">
            <a href="#" title="Click here">DECOUVRIR L'OFFRE</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--row-->
      </div>
      <!--offers-box-->
    </div>
    <!--col-md-4-->



    <div class="col-md-4 ">
      <div class="offers-box offers-last-box">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3>COMMUNICATIONS STANDARD TELEPHONIQUE</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--row-->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <p><span class="blue-color">Le portail unifie</span> de vos communications d'entreprises</p>
            <img src="/images/image.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--row-->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 text-center offers-button">
            <a href="#" title="Click here">DECOUVRIR L'OFFRE</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--row-->
      </div>
      <!--offers-box-->
    </div>
    <!--col-md-4-->

  </div>
  <!--row-->
</div>
<!--offers-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You have only one a tag inside each .offers-box, therefore :nth-of-type(1) can not work since its a zero based index.

I think this might be what you wanted to do

```
.offers-box:nth-of-type(1)  a {
    color: #3F265F;
}
.offers-box:nth-of-type(2) a {
    color: #F04B5B;
}
```